# Regions override current production enviorenment

Tags: cockpit

I'm using cockpit with regions for an email template, but
when I make a deploy it removes the version on the live system 
for the current locally of regions addon?

I have tried to apply .ignore in regions, but doesn't work at all.

Is there something that I need to do before the deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Applied the patch responsible to update this package regions.